# Finding the interval between dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

I have a table including more than 5 million rows of sales transactions. I would like to find **sum of date intervals between each customer three recent purchases**.

Suppose my table looks like this :

```
CustomerID        ProductID             ServiceStartDate     ServiceExpiryDate     
   A                X1                     2010-01-01             2010-06-01
   A                X2                     2010-08-12             2010-12-30
   B                X4                     2011-10-01             2012-01-15
   B                X3                     2012-04-01             2012-06-01
   B                X7                     2012-08-01             2013-10-01
   A                X5                     2013-01-01             2015-06-01
```

The Result that I'm looking for may looks like this :

```
CustomerID        IntervalDays 
    A                  802
    B                  135
```

I know the query need to first retrieve 3 resent transactions of each customer (based on `ServiceStartDate`) and then calculate the interval between `startDate` and `ExpiryDate` of his/her transactions.

Comment: What's your SQL Server version? Does it support LAG/LEAD (SS2012)?

Comment: Yes Sir, It is Sql Server 2012. But i don't know about LAB/LEAD @dnoeth

Comment: I added a solution using LEAD (and changed the difference calculation to DATEDIF)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to calculate the difference between the previous row's ServiceExpiryDate and the current row's ServiceStartDate based on descending dates and then sum up the last two differences:

```
with cte as
 (
   select tab.*, 
      row_number()
      over (partition by customerId
            order by ServiceStartDate desc
                   , ServiceExpiryDate desc -- don't know if this 2nd column is necessary 
           ) as rn
   from tab
 ) 
select t2.customerId,
   sum(datediff(day, prevEnd, ServiceStartDate)) as Intervaldays
   ,count(*) as purchases
from cte as t2 left join cte as t1
on t1.customerId = t2.customerId
and t1.rn = t2.rn+1     -- previous and current row
where t2.rn  <= 3       -- last three rows
group by t2.customerId;
```

Same result using LEAD:

```
with cte as
 (
   select tab.*, 
      row_number()
      over (partition by customerId
            order by ServiceStartDate desc) as rn
     ,lead(ServiceExpiryDate)
      over (partition by customerId
            order by ServiceStartDate desc
            ) as prevEnd
   from tab
 ) 
select customerId,
   sum(datediff(day, prevEnd, ServiceStartDate)) as Intervaldays
   ,count(*) as purchases
from cte 
where rn <= 3
group by customerId;
```

Both will not return the expected result unless you subtract `purchases` (or `max(rn)`) from `Intervaldays`. But as you only sum two differences this seems to be not correct for me either...

Additional logic must be applied based on your rules regarding:

- customer has less than 3 purchases
- overlapping intervals

Comment: Dear Friend, There's one question keeping my mind busy. where rn<=3 means when customers have less than 3 purchases?

Comment: Because i am looking to find the interval of their last three purchases. not customers who have less than 3 purchases @dnoeth

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER` returns a sequence number based on descending dates,  so `where rn<=3` returns up to three rows per customer which will be aggregated in the next step. If you want to exclude those customers with less than 3 purchases you can add `HAVING COUNT(*) = 3`

Comment: Thanks Man, It was so interesting what T-SQL is capable of. Can you recommend a good practical book for learning T-SQL? @dnoeth

Comment: I don't work with SQL Server anymore, but the books by Itzik Ben-Gan used to be excellent. I know him from the days back when I was a MCT for SS...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are no overlaps, I think you want this:

```
select customerId,
       sum(datediff(day, ServiceStartDate, ServieEndDate) as Intervaldays
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by customerId
                                     order by ServiceStartDate desc) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 3
group by customerId;
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, what happens if there are some overlaps? It sums a negative number with other numbers?

Comment: I guess Datediff calculate the difference of dates in one row, to have date interval between transactions i might need another method @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT dt.CustomerID,
        SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, dt.PrevExpiry, dt.ServiceStartDate)) As IntervalDays
FROM (
    SELECT *
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY ServiceStartDate DESC) AS rn
            , (SELECT Max(ti.ServiceExpiryDate) 
               FROM yourTable ti 
               WHERE t.CustomerID = ti.CustomerID 
                 AND ti.ServiceStartDate < t.ServiceStartDate) As PrevExpiry
    FROM yourTable t )dt
GROUP BY dt.CustomerID
```

Result will be:

```
CustomerId | IntervalDays
-----------+--------------
A          | 805
B          | 138
```

Comment: Sorry but which table is dt?       @shA.t